# Spring Security login with customized form

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

My Spring security configurations:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser("username").password("password")
              .authorities("USER");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and().csrf().disable();
        }

       ....
}
```

My Spring boot controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController extends BaseController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    } 
....
}
```

Hi, I am attempting to using Spring security with customized login form.
My problem is:

1. When I enter the `localhost:8080/login` The browser doesn't direct to my login.jsp, it just pops out a default form with text boxes to enter username and password.
2. After I enter "username" as username, "password" as password, it returns an authentication failed.

The traceback:

```
Request '/login' matched by universal pattern '/**'
DEBUG - matched
DEBUG - /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
DEBUG - /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
DEBUG - /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
DEBUG - /login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
DEBUG - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
DEBUG - Checking match of request : '/login'; against '/logout'
DEBUG - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
DEBUG - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
DEBUG - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
DEBUG - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
DEBUG - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
DEBUG - Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
DEBUG - No matches found
DEBUG - /login at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
DEBUG - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'username'
DEBUG - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
DEBUG - User 'username' not found
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
DEBUG - Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the anonymous user has not access to /login

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").anonymous()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
```

Overmore, looks like you are doing request against your server with the Authorization header for the Basic Authentication.

`DEBUG - Basic Authentication Authorization header found for user 'username'`